# Why does List(50) { kotlin.kotlin.Random.nextInt(0, 4) } only return 3 on the first iteration?

Tags: android, kotlin

In doing the Android Developers [Write conditionals in Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-conditionals?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-conditionals#1) tutorial, I went on a tangent and wrote and executed the following code in the [Kotlin Playground](https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground):

```
fun main() {
    var trafficLightColor: String = "";
    List(50) {
        var randomNumber: Int = kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, 4);
        if (randomNumber == 2) {
            trafficLightColor = "Green";
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 1) {
            trafficLightColor = "Yellow";
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 0) {
            trafficLightColor = "Red";
        }
        if (trafficLightColor.toLowerCase() == "red") {
        System.out.println("Stop");
        }
        else if (trafficLightColor.toLowerCase() == "yellow") {
            System.out.println("Slow");
        }
        else if (trafficLightColor.toLowerCase() == "green") {
            System.out.println("Go");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid traffic-light color")
        }
    }
}
```

However, `kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, 4)` can apparently only return the value `3` yielding the output `"Invalid traffic-light color"` on the first array iteration. Can anyone explain to me why?

(This also means I need to repeatedly run the script to see that result because there should be only a 25% chance of the first iteration returning the value `3`.)

Comment: How do you observe this behavior? I copied your code to Kotlin Playground and the output is random,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trafficLightColor` is not re-assigned if `randomNumber == 3`.

Move `var trafficLightColor: String = "";` into List lambda solves.

Comment: Thank you. I moved `var trafficLightColor: String = "";` and now my code works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The random function will always return a value between 0 and 4 (4 being exclusive). The iteration, whether it's first or last does not matter.

The problem is in the code. You haven't handled the condition in case the random function returns 3. You have to update the variable (trafficLightColor) there as well.

For example, if the random function returns 0 or 1 or 2 the variable will be updated with the relevant color and now its value will never be "".

The solution is to add else statement

```
else { 
    trafficLightColor = ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I see now the error; `trafficLightColor` will only be the empty string once because it is declared outside of the lambda expression and therefore never reset. I think the solution of moving `var trafficLightColor: String = "";` is more elegant though (less code), so I selected that as the answer while upvoting your answer.

Comment: Yes, moving it is also correct, however, just for your knowledge it will then always declare and initialize which is not optimal because unnecessary operations are being performed.